# return new Promise never returns

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to use a `promise` in my function but it never returns. This is my code:

```
function getData(id) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      DbUtil.connection.query("my query... ", [id],
        function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
              reject(error);
            } else {
              resolve(results);
            }
          }
        );
    }) 
}
```

The query works and I can see its results in the `else` block. But the function itself doesn't return. I tried adding a return statement after the `resolve`, and also after the `Promise` function itself. But it still doesn't return.

What am I missing?

EDIT: how do I know the function doesn't return? Because

```
function main() {
    var data = getData(1);
    console.log("data returned? " + data); 
}
```

in the above `main` function the log statement is never called.

Comment: "But the function itself doesn't return." — What makes you think that? You need to provide a [mcve]. In your provided code, you never call `getData`, let alone do anything to examine its return value.

Comment: @Quentin I edited the question as per your comment.

Comment: `getData` returns *a Promise*. You need to do `getData().then(data => ...)`.

Comment: "the log statement is never called" — The only way that would happen would be if (a) You never call `main()` or (b) there is an exception, in which case there would be an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the proper way to handle a promise

Try this:

```
var data;
getData(1).then(function(d) {
  console.log(d);
  data = d;
});
// Since a Promise is async, you can't log data here
```

or

```
async function main() {
  var data = await getData(1);
  console.log(data);
}
```

Note that this examples does not handle `catch` case.

Comment: That first use of `var data` is misleading too. Yes, you can do that, but no, it probably doesn't work as you or OP might expect.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? For example how do I call a log statement inside the `then` block?

Comment: Is that better ?

Comment: Yes, both these options work. Thank you for answering the question in a simple and effective way.